# C++ Serial port data received incorrectly

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port

The data that received from serial port, is not correct, and sometime changed!

```
  if (WaitCommEvent(hSerial, &eventMask, NULL))
{
    if (ReadFile(hSerial, &input, 14, &bytesRead, NULL) !=0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(input); i++)
        {
            cout << hex <<(int)input[i]<<endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "error reading file\n";
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "error waiting for comm event\n";
}
```

the data is:

```
50
ffffffaf
0
e
2
42
2
b
d
0
1
1
50
ffffffe5
```

when I get the data with Pyserial the data is:

```
50AF000E0242020B0D00010150E5
```

as you can see, I got extra 'ffffff' and missed some '0'! And because of missed data, sometimes the 'af' changed to '2f'!

Is there any wrong things with my code?

Comment: Why are you ignoring `bytesRead`?

Comment: Guess what happens when you take a `char` whose value is 0xAF, and convert it to an `(int)`? No, you will not get an `int` value with 0xAF.

Comment: If `input` is a `char` array, try declaring it as an `unsigned char` array. For example: `unsigned char input[32];`

Comment: What should I do with bytesRead? It is always 14!

Comment: I use (int) to make it readable, otherwise the data shown like »♫☻

Comment: Are you aware that there's just only byte value that's `0B` in hexadecimal? Whether you print it as `B` or `0B`, padded with an extra zero, that it makes absolutely no difference, whatsoever?

Comment: thanks @JohnnyMopp that extra ffff gone

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  0 in 0B sometimes is part of password or other important data, so I can't ignore them

Comment: If `0` is a part of a some kind of a password it would be a separate character or byte, by itself. You have no other option but to "ignore" it. This is how computers work on a fundamental level. If you have a byte containing 11, in decimal, there is absolutely nothing, whatsoever, that will tell you if it's `B` or `0B` in hexadecimal. It's the same value. If you expect that all your hexadecimal values must be shown with two digits you will need to make your code explicitly format it, as such.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the data, the data itself is fine.  It is your printing of the data that is faulty.

You are not taking into account that `input` is using a *signed* `char` type that gets [**sign-extended**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) when assigned to a *signed* `int`. That is where the extra `f`s in `ffffffaf` and `ffffffe5` are coming from when printing a `char` whose value is `0xAF` or `0xE5`, because their high bit is `1` in both cases and gets carried into the extended bits, eg:

```
0x50       =                            01010000
0x00000050 = 00000000 00000000 00000000 01010000
             <--------------------------^ 

0xAF       =                            10101111
0xFFFFFFAF = 11111111 11111111 11111111 10101111
             <--------------------------^ 

0xE5       =                            11100101
0xFFFFFFE5 = 11111111 11111111 11111111 11100101
             <--------------------------^
```

On the other hand, *unsigned* values are [**zero-extended**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) instead:

```
0x50       =                            01010000
0x00000050 = 00000000 00000000 00000000 01010000
             <-------------------------| 

0xAF       =                            10101111
0x000000AF = 00000000 00000000 00000000 10101111
             <-------------------------| 

0xE5       =                            11100101
0x000000E5 = 00000000 00000000 00000000 11100101
             <-------------------------|
```

You are also not taking into account that by default, `std::cout` with `std::hex` will print numeric values `0..15` using just 1 hex digit, so any leading `0` hex digits are not printed. `e`, `b`, `d` are the same numeric values as `0e`, `0b`, `0d`.  If you want the `0`s printed, you have to tell `std::cout` to pad out the values to at least 2 hex digits.

Try this instead:

```cpp
char input[...];
...
if (ReadFile(hSerial, &input, 14, &bytesRead, NULL))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; ++i)
    {
       cout << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(input[i])) << endl;
    }
}
```

If you change `input` to use `unsigned char` instead of `char`, then you can remove that one type-cast:

```cpp
unsigned char input[...];
...
if (ReadFile(hSerial, &input, 14, &bytesRead, NULL))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; ++i)
    {
       cout << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(input[i]) << endl;
    }
}
```